# Ajax / Javascript action doesn't appear on my main page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to create a button with a simple Ajax / Javascript command, it seems to be working however it doesnt appears on my main page (under F12) which cause some issues.

here is the code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <button class="createButton" id="create_Button" onclick='button_creation()'>Create me</button>
</body>

<script>
    function button_creation() 
    {
            button_exist = document.getElementById('submit_button');
            if(button_exist == null)
            {
                    btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    btn.innerHTML = "Submit";
                    btn.setAttribute("type","submit");
                    btn.setAttribute("name","submit");
                    btn.setAttribute("value","submit");
                    document.body.appendChild(btn);
            }
    }
</script>
```

the script works, however when i keep pressing the button it keep creating more buttons, and the reason for that (at least to me) its because it doesnt appears on the F12 of the main page.
although when i go to the console (F12) and write "document.getElementById('submit_button')"
i get all the values i entered.

anyone knows why and how do i solve that Ajax / Javascript will appear in my F12?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit F12, it is showing you the rendered source code in the browser's debugging tool. What you see may vary slightly between Chrome, Edge, FireFox, etc, as their tools vary slightly. This isn't the issue. Also, HTML rendered with JavaScript may not immediately appear in your F12 code. You may have to right click and choose to inspect the new button to get it to refresh (depending on which browser you're using).

Your code is checking for a button with an ID of submit_button. If it doesn't find it, it creates a new button. But, it doesn't assign that new button an ID value at all. So, when it checks again for buttons with an ID of submit_button, it will never find any, so it keeps making buttons. You should add an ID to your newly-created button:

```
function button_creation() 
    {
            button_exist = document.getElementById('submit_button');
            if(button_exist == null)
            {
                    btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
                    btn.innerHTML = "Submit";
                    btn.setAttribute("id","submit_button");
                    btn.setAttribute("type","submit");
                    btn.setAttribute("name","submit_button");
                    btn.setAttribute("value","submit");
                    document.body.appendChild(btn);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Omg... i can't believe i missed that... it was so simple and obvious, i guess i was too tired to noticed that, many thanks for pointing my problem.